# How can I make a button on tkinter that gets an outline when you hover over it

Tags: tkinter, button

I want the button to get an outline once I hover over it.

Figma prototype of what I'm trying to make: https://www.figma.com/proto/HbDVOwNRXqo3hfg36lOsAP/Button-Hover?page-id=0%3A1&node-id=1%3A26&viewport=241%2C417%2C0.46&scaling=min-zoom

What I have tried:

```
class LButton(tk.Button):
def __init__(self, master, text, function, *grid):
    super().__init__(
        master,
        text = text,
        command = function,
        highlightbackground = 'black'
    )
    self.bind("<Enter>", self.outlineIn(self))
    self.bind("<Leave>", self.outlineOut(self))        
    if grid == None:
        self.pack()
    else:
        self.grid(row = grid[0], column = grid[1])
def outlineIn(self, button):
    button.config(highlightthickness = 1)
def outlineOut(self, button):
    button.config(highlightthickness = 0)
```

Comment: Note that the two event callbacks are executed when binding the events, not when the events happen.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with your code. First, the calls to `bind` need to pass a reference to the function. What you're doing is immediately calling a function and the passing the result to `bind`. In both cases the result is `None`, which means nothing will be bound to the event.

```
self.bind("<Enter>", self.outlineIn)
self.bind("<Leave>", self.outlineOut)
```

Second, bound functions always receive an object representing the event. You need to take that into consideration when defining the functions. Instead of accepting the button object, accept an event object from which you can get the widget.

```
def outlineIn(self, event):
    event.widget.config(highlightthickness = 1)
def outlineOut(self, event):
    event.widget.config(highlightthickness = 0)
```

Note: changing the `highlightthickness` will cause the button to jump around a bit when you hover the mouse over it. Instead, you might want to consider changing the `highlightbackground` either to red or to the same color as the background of the parent widget.

Comment: Yeah you're right giving the button an outer outline will cause it to jump around a bit, in my figma design I used an inner outline so that I didn't have to deal with this issue, is there a way for me to do that in tkinter?

Comment: @redpz: you could put the button inside a frame, and use the frame for the colored border.